# Press Enter inside input field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, events

Is there a way to to active a function when I press enter in input field?
Because now when I press enter, the page reload.
thank you

```js
CForm className="form-horizontal">
              <CFormGroup row className="condidateContainrer">
                <CCol md="4 mt-3">
                  <CLabel>Name of condidate:</CLabel>
                </CCol>
                <CCol md="7 mt-2">
                  <CInput
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Search Here"
                    onChange={(e) => {
                      setCondidateName(e.target.value);
                      
                    }}
                  />
                </CCol>
                <CButton
                  color="success"
                  variant="outline"
                  onClick={() =>
                    setAddCandidate([...addCandidate, condidateName])
                  }
                >
                  +
                </CButton>
              </CFormGroup>
            </CForm>
```

Comment: You can use `keyDown` event to identify if enter has been pressed

Comment: Thatnks, it worked.